# Javascript timezone-offset different depending on the year of the date

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset

When instantiating a date in Javascript the timezone-offset differs depending on the year.
I live in Belgium so the utc timezone offset is +1.

Starting from year 1943 the timezone seems to be as expected but before it gives different result depending on the year.

For example (you can try it out in jsfiddle.net):

```
// All dates are 1 january, only the year differs

console.log(new Date(1900,0,1).toString())
// Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date(1940,0,1).toString())
// Mon Jan 01 1940 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date(1941,0,1).toString())
// Wed Jan 01 1941 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date(1943,0,1).toString())
// Fri Jan 01 1943 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(new Date(2013,0,1).toString())
// Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Can someone explain why the timezone offset differs depending on the year?

Comment: Do no use old times. Recent timezone files cover only recent years (some sort of "unification", so losing historical information but for for Berlin, and few other cities). And also... do you want to rely on user browsers for such data?

Comment: You can read the full commented history of _why_ in the TZ Database.  Here's Belgium:  https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/0bb92ae8f46dc05a62a5904103d4cbfa761730b4/europe#L876-L960

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, it helped to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the Daylight saving time offset and time zone offset changes. A country's government could change them periodically.

That's the reason you shouldn't do your datetime math manually on seconds but use JS Date functions. JS has full knowledge of the history of DST and time zone changes for a particular location / time zone label.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: Thank you for your input, at least it clarifies the behavior.

We choose for the simple solution: not allowing old dates which is practical in our case.

Comment: Great, glad it helped somehow, you are welcome. you could also upvote my answer (the arrow up), thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that, done.